# Python telegram bot получить номер телефона после отправки

Tags: python, telegram, бот

```
        @bot.message_handler(commands=["geophone"])
        def geophone(message):
            keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
            button_phone = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить номер телефона", request_contact=True)
            button_geo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить местоположение", request_location=True)
            keyboard.add(button_phone, button_geo)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправь мне свой номер", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

В чём хранится номер телефона? Как мне получить номер телефона если пользователь согласился и отправил его мне?

Comment: Попробуйте получить информацию о пользователе. После отправки телефона, поле `phone` должно быть не `None`. Какую библиотеку используете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Он нигде не хранится, это отдельное сообщение, которое нужно принять и обработать.
Для этого воспользуйтесь декоратором

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["contact"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы задала callback_data для каждой кнопки. С помощью лямбды или 'if'сделала бы функцию, где человек бы вводил номер телефона. А потом бы вывела его в message.text

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте в ответе сослагательное наклонение: "Я бы сделал ...", "Я бы вывел ...". Привидите код, который решает задачу  в вопросе, и напишите: "Я сделал так, проверил, работает.". А пока, ваше сообщение не более чем комментарий.